# Using LSTM with GEKKO MPC

Tags: lstm, gekko

After using GEKKO to model a ARX MPC based on process data for multi-stage evaporation station, I wanted to see how the prediction model stand up to an LSTM prediction control, however I have trouble connecting
the LSTM model (saved as .h5) to the GEKKO MPC.

Hence my 2 questions

1. Is it possible to use an LSTM with GEKKO?
2. Do there exist literature or cases where this have been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gekko doesn’t allow models from other packages such as the `h5` model but it could probably be created if you have the drive to translate the model. Here are two options:

1. Convert the RNN model to Gekko format. There is an example of a Keras neural network model and [Gekko neural network model](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DeepLearning). Gekko allows [additional activation functions](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DeepLearning?action=sourceblock&num=8) beyond the typical and uses a different strategy (nonlinear programming solvers) for regression.

[image: Keras Neural Network]

2. Use a [shooting method for MPC with an optimizer](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/ModelPredictiveControl) like scipy.optimize.minimize(). There is an example of this approach at the bottom.

[image: MPC Python]